# Laravel 5 Swift_TransportException "550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender "

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, smtp

I am trying to send mail with relay mail server using smtp in laravel but I am getting this error:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

"

I am using Centos server.When doing telnet like this:

```
Connected to relay.*****.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 MSEXCFE04.***** Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 11 Jan 2017 14:11:25 +0300
mail from:test@***.com
503 5.5.2 Send hello first
```

After this doing `HELO` server sending mail.

But in laravel I am getting trouble with above error.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42752270/386579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your email provider is checking your sendind information. So, if you are not part of the Apple company, you cannot send an email as being @apple.com, can you? This is known as forgery. So

```
 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

Basically is saying that the domain you are trying to send to is not yours, or the server you are using to send it from, does not have rights to send emails for this particular domain.

This is probably being done by a SPF policy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework