# PHPMailer is giving me the following error

Tags: php, email, office365, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer, and when I tried to run the following PHP I got this error message:

Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender SMTP code: 550

php code:

```
<?php

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'outlook.office365.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'info@domain.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*password*';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
// $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
// $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}


?>
```

Comment: I would guess that `from@example.com` is not a valid account on your Office365 account

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just changed it and it still did not work. Any other Ideas. Do I need to change somthing in other files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947434/setting-up-phpmailer-with-office365-smtp

Comment: You might try `smtp.office365.com` as your HOST, `outlook.office365.com` is the url for POP3

Comment: @Binary111 you have to got your gmail account and then setting and then you have to make sure that less secure app permission is ok.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it could be much clearer when it says "Client does not have permissions to send as this sender". It means exactly what it says.

You are sending using a from address (which by default is also used as the envelope sender; see the `Sender` property) of `from@example.com`, and outlook is not willing to let you use that address. You will probably be limited to using the address that is also your user name. Gmail has a similar limitation.